# Python delete duplicate nodes within an XML file

Tags: python, xml, duplicates, nodes

I have to clean many XML files with this structure :

```
<Corps_TTL> 
      <Id_TTL>60006</Id_TTL>
      <Donnees_Releve> <!-- could be many -->
         <Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure> <!-- could be many -->
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPH</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>0</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPH</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>0</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPE</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>1072</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle> <!-- could have many or none duplicate node for this Classe_Temporelle value depending on the file-->
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPE</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>1072</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
         </Donnees_Releve>
</Corps_TTL>
```

And I wrote a Python script that deduplicate Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle with the same Classe_Temporelle value. The goal is to get an output file looking like this :

```
<Corps_TTL> 
          <Id_TTL>60006</Id_TTL>
          <Donnees_Releve> <!-- could be many -->
             <Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure> <!-- could be many -->
                <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
                   <Classe_Temporelle>HPH</Classe_Temporelle>
                   <Quantite_Mesure>0</Quantite_Mesure>
                </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
                <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle> <!-- only one node for this Classe_Temporelle value -->
                   <Classe_Temporelle>HPE</Classe_Temporelle> 
                   <Quantite_Mesure>1072</Quantite_Mesure>
                </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
             </Donnees_Releve>
    </Corps_TTL>
```

Please find below the code I wrote, I do not understand why it do not work, maybe because I look for an attribute and note an element value. The thing is that I don't find out how to fix it.

```
import pprint
import os
import copy
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

folder_path = "/files/IN/"
out_folder_path = "/files/OUT/"

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(".xml"):
            print("parsing : "+filename)
            tree = ET.parse(folder_path + filename)
            root = tree.getroot()
            #on boucle sur chaque PRM
            for dr in root.iter('Donnees_Releve'):
                print("-----------------------")  
                for dtm in dr.iter('Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure'):
                    #print type of node
                    print('node # : ' + dtm.find('Type_Mesure').text)
                    #loop on Donnees_Releve

                    # Use a `set` to keep track of "visited" elements with good lookup time.
                    visited = set()
                    # The iter method does a recursive traversal
                    for el in dtm.iter('Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle'):
                        # Since the id is what defines a duplicate for you
                        if 'Classe_Temporelle' in el.attr:
                            current = el.find('Classe_Temporelle').text
                            # In visited already means it's a duplicate, remove it
                            if current in visited:
                                el.getparent().remove(el)
                                # Otherwise mark this ID as "visited"
                            else:
                                visited.add(current)
                    
            tree.write(out_folder_path+filename)
```

Could you please bring some help to finish that script ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''

<Corps_TTL> 
      <Id_TTL>60006</Id_TTL>
      <Donnees_Releve> <!-- could be many -->
         <Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure> <!-- could be many -->
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPH</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>0</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPH</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>0</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPE</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>1072</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPE</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>1072</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
          </Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure>
         </Donnees_Releve>
</Corps_TTL> '''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for entry_1 in root.findall('.//Donnees_Releve'):
  for entry_2 in entry_1.findall('.//Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure'):
    classe_temporelle_values = set()
    for entry_3 in entry_2.findall('.//Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle'):
      classe_temporelle = entry_3.find('./Classe_Temporelle')
      classe_temporelle_value = classe_temporelle.text
      if classe_temporelle_value not in classe_temporelle_values:
        classe_temporelle_values.add(classe_temporelle_value)
      else:
        entry_2.remove(entry_3)
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<Corps_TTL> 
      <Id_TTL>60006</Id_TTL>
      <Donnees_Releve> 
         <Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure> 
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPH</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>0</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            <Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
               <Classe_Temporelle>HPE</Classe_Temporelle>
               <Quantite_Mesure>1072</Quantite_Mesure>
            </Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle>
            </Donnees_Par_Type_Mesure>
         </Donnees_Releve>
</Corps_TTL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I forgot to explain that Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle of input XML could contain sometimes 10 Conso_Par_Classe_Temporelle with a lot of duplicate value for Classe_Temporelle (and not only 4 nodes as in example), does that script could be adapted to manage this ?

Comment: Try the code on a more complex xml (as you just mentioned)

Comment: It look that it works great ! Many many thanks for your precious help